# Pop up disappears when a img button in clicked (ASP.NET Ajax control tool kit)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, popup, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
   <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Controls" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_Edit" ToolTip="Edit User" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' CommandName="Edit" runat="server"><img id="img_Edit" src="Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" runat="server" style="border-style: none" alt="Edit User" /></asp:LinkButton>

                            <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopUCtrlExt_Edit" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
                            Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="img_Edit" PopupControlID="PanelCreateUser">
                        </asp:PopupControlExtender>
```

I am using Ajax to do a pop up. I am able to pop up the panel when I click the img id="img_Edit" . But what happens is when I click the pop up appears and a post back happens as a result the panel disappears. I even tried to put the grid inside a update panel but didn't work. what Should I do to make the pop up stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `OnClientClick="return false;"` for `LinkButton`, like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_Edit" OnClientClick="return false;" ToolTip="Edit User" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' CommandName="Edit" runat="server"><img id="img_Edit" src="Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" runat="server" style="border-style: none" alt="Edit User" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: hmm i see, you can two things to solve this: 1. If you need a postback then call PopUCtrlExt_Edit.Show(); in Edit command, it will still show the popup after postback is complete ---- or ---- 2. you can register LinkButton as AsyncPostBack control, for this in your Page_Load paste this sciptMgr.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(linkFileBtn); where scriptMgr is the id of ScriptManager and linkFileBtn is the id of link button....